# Will Google preserve URL parameters when indexing my site if the explicit in the site and/or site map

Tags: seo, google, url, search-engine-indexing

I have written some functionality that opens tabbed content on page when visiting a page via a URL with certain parameters.

What i have been asked is that will Google, or any other search engine, preserve these URL parameters once my site has been indexed? Therefore when a user that receives said URL as a result visits the site the functionality will be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. URLs with parameters are returned as part of search results and will behave normally when clicked upon.

However, this may cause duplicate content issues if those tabs are just hidden DIVs on the page and are shown/hidden when the proper parameters is passed via the URL. You can solve the duplicate content issue with canonical URLs but then only one URL will show in the search results which is counterproductive to your goals. If the content is not hidden/present on the page and is dynamically generated upon each page load then you will have no issues.